# Convert perl script to vba

Tags: vba, perl, vbscript, porting

I am using a PC where perl script is not allowed. Is there any tool to convert perl script to vba macro?

Or is there any links where we can get the vba equavalent of perl statements.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've got access to a machine that can run Perl, you could try using the [PAR Packer utility (pp)](http://p3rl.org/pp).

```
% pp -o hello hello.pl      
# Pack 'hello.pl' into executable 'hello'
# (or 'hello.exe' on Win32)
```

Comment: Thank you Corey, I will try and get back

Comment: I tried in a machine that has Perl.. but pp command is not recognized.. Please help

Comment: You need to install it from CPAN.

Comment: Thank you @triplee , But I am not allowed to install any software

Answer (score -1):

If you have enough permissions to run VB scripts, you should also have permissions to install the Perl interpreter and just run your script natively.

Comment: Thanks for the info Nilpo. I can run a vba code from excel macro. But I am not allowed to install Perl interpreter or any new software.

Comment: @Nilpo: There's a difference between having privileges on a machine and having permission to install software.  The latter is determined by people, not by software.

Comment: @RamseyNorton: Running a VBA macro is slightly different than pure VBScript but it shouldn't present a problem in most cases.  If you can post your Perl script, I'd be happy to see about porting it over for you.

Comment: @Jonathan: I agree with your statement.  I was more or less suggesting that in 99% of all configurations I've encountered professionally, they are both restricted or unrestricted equally.  You seldom see a scenario where one is allowed and the other is not.

Comment: Thank you Nilpo. But I cant even access this web page from that system. I will write a similar perl script using all the statements I used in that and post soon.

Comment: Here is my requirement:1. loop through all text files in a folder(path is available in srcfolder variable) 2. For each text file create a css file. 3. read each text file line by line. 4. if the statement contains a specific string transform the statement using a regex and print it in csv file. 5. once all statements in a text file are parsed delete the text file

Comment: I am unable to paste my perl script here. it contains @ in the statements. when i click add comment it says. only one additional @ user can be notified :(.............Below I have pasted a mini version of the 700 line perl script and replaced @ with @_ to avoid it to be recognized as @user

Comment: $srcfolder="c:\temp\";
@_textFiles = <$srcfolder*.txt>;
foreach $textFile(@textFiles)
{
 open INFILE,"<",$textFile;
 @_textContents= <INFILE>; 
 open OUTFILE,">",$textFile.".csv";
 for($i=0;$i<$#textContents;$i++)
    {
  $var=@_textContents[$i]; 
  if($var=~/<data/)
                {
                    $var=~s/<data//;                   
      $var=~s/\s+//; 
      $var=~s/\n// 
      $var=~s/'(.*)//; 
                }
  elsif($var=~/<end/)
  {
      goto endfile;
  } 
  print OUTFILE $var;
 } 
endfile:
}
close(INFILE);
close(OUTFILE);
@_tfiles = <$srcfolder*.txt>;
unlink @_tfiles;