# How do I translate this code from Visual Basic to Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, excel, sharepoint-2010, vba

I am trying to export an Excel spreadsheet to SharePoint. I recorded the Visual Basic code, and now I want to translate it to Perl. I tried like this but it didn't work.

I don't get any error, but I also don't see the list in the Sharepoint. When I did it using the macro in Excel it worked

```
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';

my $excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
$excel->{'Visible'} = 1;
$excel->{DisplayAlerts} = 1;

my $book = $excel->Workbooks->Open("C:\\Book1.xlsx")
    || die("Unable to open document ", Win32::OLE->LastError());

my $list = $book->ActiveSheet->ListObjects("Table1")->Publish Array("https:\/\/sponsor\/sites\/dev_test_site", "myname"), False;
```

The original Visual Basic code

```
Sub Macro1()

  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Publish Array( _
    "https://sponsor/sites/dev_test_site", "myname"), False
  Range("C2").Select
End Sub
```

Eventually I came up with this code

```
my $excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
$excel->{'Visible'} = 1;
$excel->{DisplayAlerts} = 1;

my $book = $excel->Workbooks->Open("C:\\Book1.xlsm")
    || die("Unable to open document ", Win32::OLE->LastError());

my @array=("https:\/\/sponsor\/sites\/dev_test_site", "aaaa");

my $list= $book->ActiveSheet->ListObjects("hhhh")->Publish(@array, 0);
```

And this image shows the result

[image]

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean- what error message do you get? Is there a specific reason you need to use Perl for this? It's the kind of job that Powershell is fairly well equipped for as it ties in naturally to the .Net platform stuff Sharepoint and Excel interoperate through.

Comment: i don't get any error. but i also don't see the list in the sharepoint. when i did it using the macro in excel it worked.

Comment: Please don't use images of text in your questions. Copy and paste the information where at all possible.

Answer (score 3):

You should `use strict` and `use warnings`. It will proceed to tell you a number of error messages then.

What I can make out from the Perl code you posted without running it is:

```
my $list= $book->ActiveSheet->ListObjects("Table1")->Publish Array("https:\/\/sponsor\/sites\/dev_test_site", "myname"), False;
```

Note that there is a space between `Publish` and `Array(`. That has to be a problem. The only way to have a function cal followed by something other than `(` or `;` or `,` is if it has prototypes. But method calls in object oriented Perl cannot have prototypes. So that is definitely wrong.

Then there's `Array(...)`. There is no built-in function called `Array` and I do not think that Win32::OLE::Const exports that, though I did not look. Even if it did, you told it to only export `'Microsoft Excel'`. The same goes for `False`.

I suggest you read the [documentation of Win32::OLE::Const](http://p3rl.org/Win32%3a%3aOLE%3a%3aConst) and add `use strict` and `use warnings`. There are also some resources of how to work with Win32 modules on [Sinan Ünürs blog](http://blog.nu42.com/search?q=win32).

Comment: can you help me with the publish array function? i can't find anywhere how to use it in Perl.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SharePoint I'm afraid. I can only tell you what's syntactically wrong with your code. Sorry.

Comment: i only need to find out how to write the publish array function in Perl. it has nothing to do with SharePoint . i can't find anywhere the methods for ListObjects

Comment: i updated the question. maybe you know how to solve the error?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this: [Convert perl script to vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323811/convert-perl-script-to-vba) This already has some answers.

You may need to follow this script. `% pp -o hello hello.pl` or something like that.

Comment: i have a VBA code that works, i want to convert it to Perl script